# Unable to access knockout method being in loop inside with

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a parent model something like this

```
function VM() {
    var self = this;
    self.MyPage =   ko.observable()

}   

var vm = new VM()
```

Then i have child model like this.

```
var page = function(parent) {
    var self    = this
    self.Info   =   ko.observable()

    self.LoadData   =   function(){
        self.GetNext()
    }

    self.GetNext = function(){
        var url     =   'Questions/GetNext'
        var type    =   'GET'
        ajax(url , null , self.OnGetNextComplete, type )                    
    }
    self.OnGetNextComplete = function(data){
        self.Info(data.Payload)
    }


    self.AcceptedChoices = function(data,choiceId){
        return in_array(choiceId,data.AcceptedChoices) ? 'selected' : ''
    }
    self.LoadData()
}
```

And here is how i am using it.

```
vm.MyPage(new page(vm))
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

all works fine for the time being. Now to use the child on a page i use `with binding` like this.

```
`<body data-bind="with:MyPage">`
```

This lets me use child on the current page. 
Next i am binding like this.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:Info">
    <article>
        <h2 data-bind="text:QuestionText"></h2>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:Choices">
            <li data-bind="text:ChoiceText,css:$parent.AcceptedChoices()"></li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</div>
```

And here is the info json

```
{
    "Choices": [{
        "ChoiceId": 102,
        "ChoiceText": "Not at all"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 103,
        "ChoiceText": "Somewhat"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 104,
        "ChoiceText": "Very important"
    }],
    "QuestionText": "My personal religious beliefs are important"
},{
    "Choices": [{
        "ChoiceId": 99,
        "ChoiceText": "Never"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 100,
        "ChoiceText": "Sometimes"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 101,
        "ChoiceText": "Always"
    }],
    "QuestionText": "I am a leader"
}, 
{
    "Choices": [{
        "ChoiceId": 96,
        "ChoiceText": "Never"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 97,
        "ChoiceText": "Sometimes"
    }, {
        "ChoiceId": 98,
        "ChoiceText": "Always"
    }],
    "QuestionText": "I manage time properly"
}
```

The problem is that it always says `$parent.AcceptedChoices` is undefined. I have used `root , parent[1] , parent[2]` etc but nothing is working. How can i do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a thing against the ; character?

Comment: no i never use semicolon in javascript still it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a new view model it is not explicitly creating the relationship you are looking for from the child back to the parent.  Creating a $parent of a child is done when you create a new context within an existing context.  This is accomplished when you do something like this -

```
// Context of myPage
<div data-bind="with: myPage">
    // Each instance of Info creates it's own context
    <div data-bind="foreach:Info">
        // Now you can reference the $parent object, whi
        <article data-bind="with: $parent.selectedInfo">
        </article>
        // Or you can reference the parent's parent, which has myPage within it's context
        <article data-bind="with: $parents[1].myPage">
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because the context is creating new a context within it's own scope.

What you are doing is referencing a separate view model which has it's own context.  To access the parent view model you could do something like this -

```
var page = function(parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.Info = ko.observable();
    self.parentVM = parent;
}
```

Where you define that parent in this context should refer to the parent view model being passed in.  Then you could call this from your view model as such -

```
<div data-bind="with: parentVM.myPage"></div>
```

Of course this is psuedo code so you may need to tweak it to work how you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need to use MyPage context as you see the AcceptedChoices is defined there. I need to access it somehow. I just tried like this and it works. `$root.MyPage().AcceptedChoices`

Comment: You can reference the myPage context as I posted in my answer using parentVM.MyPage() because you are passing that into the new page() method...